# HTML5 in mobile phone

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mobile

I have this :

```
Response.Write("<embed height='0' width='0' src='Ses.wav' />");
```

This works and plays sound in desktop browser,

but doesn't work in `mobile browser`.

What can be the reason
and what do I have to do to run this on IOS and Android?

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
Response.Write("<audio controls='controls'> <source src='Ses.wav' type='audio/wav'></audio>");
```